# Speechmatics Python Code fails to use Google Cloud Storage signed url with fetch_data

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am experimenting with Speechmatics Transcription API using a file in Google Cloud Storage with a signed url.

The [SpeechMatics Document](https://docs.speechmatics.com/features-other/fetch-url) says that I have to use fetch_data parameter in order to provide a URL to the config file.

But when I try to use [submit_job](https://docs.speechmatics.com/introduction/batch-guide) function with the fetch_data parameter, my understanding is that I have to use the API call with requests library directly.

Until this point I had no luck with the following code :

```
import requests
import logging
from django.conf import settings

logger = logging.getLogger('speechmatics')

class SpeechMatics():
    def submit_file(audio_url, webhook_url, lang):
        # Define request parameters
        url = 'https://asr.api.speechmatics.com/v2/jobs'
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + settings.SPEECHMATICS_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
        logger.info("Submitting transcription job to Speechmatics API...")
        logger.info("audio_url type: {}".format(type(audio_url)))
        logger.info("API URL: {}".format(url))
        logger.info("API headers: {}".format(headers))
        payload = {
            "type": "transcription",
            "transcription_config": { 
                "language": lang,
                "diarization": "speaker",
            },
            "fetch_data": {
                "url": audio_url
            }
        }
        logger.info("API payload: {}".format(payload))

        # Send the request
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
            # response.raise_for_status()  # raise HTTPError for non-2xx response status codes

            logger.info("Speechmatics API response: {}".format(response.json()))
            logger.info("API response status code: {}".format(response.status_code))
            logger.info("API response headers: {}".format(response.headers))

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            logger.error("Speechmatics API request failed: {}".format(e))
            raise  # re-raise the exception to be handled at a higher level
```

Although my payload and config seems to be fine. I keep getting following 400 error message :

```
[speechmatics.py:18] API headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
[speechmatics.py:29] API payload: {'type': 'transcription', 'transcription_config': {'language': 'en', 'diarization': 'speaker'}, 'fetch_data': {'url': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging-videoo-storage-7/8bdcf5aa-a998-440a-870d-7c31de591aca?...'}}
[speechmatics.py:36] Speechmatics API response: {'code': 400, 'message': 'no multipart boundary param in Content-Type'}
[speechmatics.py:37] API response status code: 400
[speechmatics.py:38] API response headers: {'Content-Length': '68', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains', 'Request-Id': '6126c67c56f12b5042b7e4f78b4632aa', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization', 'Access-Control-Max-Age': '1728000', 'X-Cache': 'CONFIG_NOCACHE', 'X-Azure-Ref': '0AWAjZAAAAAB5KJjEElURTa7s+0gal3wqTUFOMzBFREdFMDMwNwBhN2JjOWQ4MC02YjBiLTQ1NWEtYjE3MS01NGJkZmNiYWE0YTk=', 'Date': 'Tue, 28 Mar 2023 21:45:36 GMT'}
```

What shall I do, in order to make a successful call to Speechmatics API with a Google Cloud Storage Signedurl?

Comment: The error means that the API is expecting `multipart/form-data` but the HTTP POST request body is `JSON`. Try again after deleting this header from the request: `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: Security warning: The question shows the `Bearer Token`. Make sure that you have deleted that token in your management interface.

Comment: Editing the question to delete the token does not actually delete the token. Revision edits are still visible.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki to help others that can encounter this issue.

As stated by @John Hanley:
The error means that the API is expecting multipart/form-data but the HTTP POST request body is JSON. Deleting the header `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` will resolve the issue.